# Gearman: 3 seconds between client request and worker receive. Is this normal?

Tags: php, gearman

Environment:

- Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop & Server
- PHP 5.3.10
- Gearman (libgearman 1.1.5 with PHP Extension 1.1.1)
- Multiple servers on LAN

I've been working on distributed processes for some time. Most of these tools require DB access. Eventually this led to server/resource issues due to MySQL getting overwhelmed (as far as I can tell).

I've tried a number of solutions and now I'm trying Gearman. I have queries being sent to workers and I'm getting the correct response back to the client. (I haven't yet tested out returning errors.)

My problem is that my test code has 3 sql statements - all selects. Probably 4 times out of 5 when I run this test script 2 or the queries take 3 sec to return and 1 takes less 0.01 sec to complete. On the 5th attempt with this script all 3 queries take 3 sec. The query that takes less than 0.01 sec is often times the last query but not always. And I have a direct DB connection executing the same queries and they all return in the 0.002 sec range.

This behavior doesn't appear to change whether I run 1 or up to 4 workers. The client is using doHigh.

Specifically here are some times (in seconds or Unix Epoch time) from my latest test run:

- Execution Time of Worker: 0.00066
- Client Job Request Time: 1380128735.505
- Worker Job Received Time: 1380128744.3248
- Client Receive Result Time: 1380128744.3262

Obviously this request took about 9 seconds not 3. The client and worker both reside on the same machine. The job server is open to the LAN so it is listening on 192.168.1.XX instead of 127.0.0.1. Sending the job to a job server on a different machine (faster, more RAM, almost no load) the times are effectively the same.

Is this the expected behavior of Gearman?

Thanks

Per suggestions on another forum I logged what was happening using --verbose=DEBUG. Long story short the gaps in time appear to be happening btwn Sent NOOP to 192.168.1... and 192.168.1... Ready  POLLIN -> ... Here is a relevant log excerpt (wish I knew how to format it better):

> INFO 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873141 [  main ] Accepted connection from
>   192.168.1.70:39280   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873200 [     3 ] Received CON wakeup event -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:602 
>   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873244 [     3 ] setsockopt() 33 ->
>   libgearman-server/io.cc:809   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873276 [     3
>   ]    192.168.1.70:39280 Watching  POLLIN  ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151    INFO 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873292 [     3 ] Gear connection made   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873309 [     3 ] 192.168.1.70:39280 Ready     POLLIN  ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:118   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873333 [     3 ] read 22 bytes -> libgearman-server/io.cc:686
>   INFO 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873346 [     3 ] Gear unpack   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:43.873363 [     3 ] GEAR length: 0
>   gearmand_command_t: GEARMAN_COMMAND_OPTION_REQ ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:248   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:43.873375 [     3 ] Received OPTION_REQ
>   192.168.1.70:3093758901 -> libgearman-server/thread.cc:318   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873399 [     3 ]    192.168.1.70:39280 Watching 
>   POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873411 [  proc ]    192.168.1.70:39280 packet command 
>   OPTION_REQ -> libgearman-server/server.cc:98   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873457 [  proc ] 'exceptions' ->
>   libgearman-server/server.cc:485   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873492 [
>   3 ] Received RUN wakeup event ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:607   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873508 [     3 ] GEAR length: 0 gearmand_command_t:
>   GEARMAN_COMMAND_OPTION_RES ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:274   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:43.873551 [     3 ] send() 22 bytes to peer
>   192.168.1.70:39280 -> libgearman-server/io.cc:275   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873565 [     3 ] Sent OPTION_RES to 192.168.1.70:-1201208395
>   -> libgearman-server/thread.cc:365   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873583 [     3 ] 192.168.1.70:39280 Ready     POLLIN  ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:118   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873599 [     3 ] read 177 bytes ->
>   libgearman-server/io.cc:686    INFO 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873610 [     3
>   ] Gear unpack   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873635 [     3 ] GEAR
>   length: 118 gearmand_command_t: GEARMAN_COMMAND_SUBMIT_JOB_HIGH ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:248   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:43.873648 [     3 ] Received SUBMIT_JOB_HIGH
>   192.168.1.70:3093758901 -> libgearman-server/thread.cc:318   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873668 [     3 ]    192.168.1.70:39280 Watching 
>   POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873675 [  proc ]    192.168.1.70:39280 packet command 
>   SUBMIT_JOB_HIGH -> libgearman-server/server.cc:98   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873696 [  proc ] Received submission, function:db_access
>   unique:e692b4c2-2654-11e3-bc34-90e6baa255ea with 2 arguments ->
>   libgearman-server/server.cc:231   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873715 [ 
>   proc ] Comparing queue 0 to limit 0 for priority 0 ->
>   libgearman-server/job.cc:174  NOTICE 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873754 [ 
>   proc ] accepted,db_access,e692b4c2-2654-11e3-bc34-90e6baa255ea,0 ->
>   libgearman-server/server.cc:301   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873764 [
>   3 ] Received RUN wakeup event ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:607   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873763 [     4 ] Received RUN wakeup event ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:607   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:43.873794 [     3 ] GEAR length: 0 gearmand_command_t:
>   GEARMAN_COMMAND_JOB_CREATED ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:274   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:43.873803 [     4 ] GEAR length: 0
>   gearmand_command_t: GEARMAN_COMMAND_NOOP ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:274   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:43.873824 [     3 ] send() 25 bytes to peer
>   192.168.1.70:39280 -> libgearman-server/io.cc:275   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873838 [     3 ] Sent JOB_CREATED to 192.168.1.70:-1201208395
>   -> libgearman-server/thread.cc:365   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873850 [     4 ] send() 12 bytes to peer 192.168.1.70:39219 ->
>   libgearman-server/io.cc:275   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:43.873865 [     4
>   ] Sent NOOP to 192.168.1.70:-1201209827 ->
>   libgearman-server/thread.cc:365   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.032010 [
>   4 ] 192.168.1.70:39219 Ready     POLLIN  ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:118   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.032061 [     4 ] read 12 bytes -> libgearman-server/io.cc:686
>   INFO 2013-09-26 02:39:47.032074 [     4 ] Gear unpack   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:47.032086 [     4 ] GEAR length: 0
>   gearmand_command_t: GEARMAN_COMMAND_GRAB_JOB_ALL ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:248   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:47.032098 [     4 ] Received GRAB_JOB_ALL
>   192.168.1.70:3093757469 -> libgearman-server/thread.cc:318   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.032119 [     4 ]    192.168.1.70:39219 Watching 
>   POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.032134 [  proc ]    192.168.1.70:39219 packet command 
>   GRAB_JOB_ALL -> libgearman-server/server.cc:98   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.032170 [  proc ] Jobs available for db_access: 1 ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:291   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.032200 [  proc ] Sending reduce submission, Partitioner:
>   db_access(9) Reducer: (0) Unique:
>   e692b4c2-2654-11e3-bc34-90e6baa255ea(36) with data sized (118) ->
>   libgearman-server/server.cc:607   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.032239 [
>   4 ] Received RUN wakeup event ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:607   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.032254 [     4 ] GEAR length: 118 gearmand_command_t:
>   GEARMAN_COMMAND_JOB_ASSIGN_ALL ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:274   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:47.032290 [     4 ] send() 192 bytes to peer
>   192.168.1.70:39219 -> libgearman-server/io.cc:275   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.032303 [     4 ] Sent JOB_ASSIGN_ALL to
>   192.168.1.70:-1201209827 -> libgearman-server/thread.cc:365   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.034398 [     4 ] 192.168.1.70:39219 Ready
>   POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:118   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.034416 [     4 ] read 1926 bytes ->
>   libgearman-server/io.cc:686    INFO 2013-09-26 02:39:47.034427 [     4
>   ] Gear unpack   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.034438 [     4 ] GEAR
>   length: 1900 gearmand_command_t: GEARMAN_COMMAND_WORK_COMPLETE ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:248   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:47.034462 [     4 ] Received WORK_COMPLETE
>   192.168.1.70:3093757469 -> libgearman-server/thread.cc:318   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.034479 [     4 ]    192.168.1.70:39219 Watching 
>   POLLIN  -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:151   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.034485 [  proc ]    192.168.1.70:39219 packet command 
>   WORK_COMPLETE -> libgearman-server/server.cc:98   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.034526 [     3 ] Received RUN wakeup event ->
>   libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:607   DEBUG 2013-09-26
>   02:39:47.034542 [     3 ] GEAR length: 1900 gearmand_command_t:
>   GEARMAN_COMMAND_WORK_COMPLETE ->
>   libgearman-server/plugins/protocol/gear/protocol.cc:274   DEBUG
>   2013-09-26 02:39:47.034577 [     3 ] send() 1926 bytes to peer
>   192.168.1.70:39280 -> libgearman-server/io.cc:275   DEBUG 2013-09-26 02:39:47.034591 [     3 ] Sent WORK_COMPLETE to
>   192.168.1.70:-1201208395 -> libgearman-serve

r/thread.cc:365

Comment: No, this is not expected. Create a worker that does absolutely nothing (except for return) and see if you still have the delay. If you don't, the content of your worker code might be the issue, if you do .. add the minimum worker code to see if it's replicable - and include gearman version numbers.

Comment: I'll try a basically empty worker. However, that Execution Time above is the time from start to finish of the function being called within the worker. And that time is consistently less than 0.001 sec. The difference between when the Client sent the job (Client Job Request Time above) and when the worker receives the job (Worker Job Received Time above) is consistently the big number. However, I'll check it out with an essentially empty worker. On another forum it was suggested that I turn on logging (DEBUG mode) for the job server.

Comment: I had the worker loop internal to a wrapper class. I thought that was the issue - even wrote up an answer to the question related to that being the case. However, upon further investigation I've found that it relates not to the wrapper class but the fact that the wrapper class attempted to connect to a job server that isn't running. I had written a basic worker script that got the response time down to about 0.003 sec which was good enough for me. However, when I added the addServer command for the down server the response time went back up to 3 sec.